# PHP SQL Query to compare DATE from predefined datetime format

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

My datetime format on my SQL Table  looks like this

Table1:

```
Col1
FromDate
--------------------------
10 August 2017 - 02:10 pm



Col2
ToDate
--------------------------
10 August 2017 - 08:00 pm
```

- What would be the applicable SQL SELECT query and or php code to check if ..

  `$submitFrdate = "10 August 2017 - 3:00PM";`
  `$submitTodate = "10 August 2017 - 6:00PM";`

  will be compared to the table using it's DATE only if any of the dates from either the first or second variable collides to the dates of any of the 2 table columns? I understand that I can trim the time stamp using `substr()` to make it into just `10 August 2017` but the data on the table includes the time. Other than that, I am not sure whats the easiest way to make sure either of the submitted data doesn't hit either of the column's dates REGARDLESS of the time.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a function called [`STR_TO_DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) which can reverse-format a date string into MySQL's native date format. Then you can do comparisons in the SQL.

Perhaps better solution is to use the [`DATETIME`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-types.html) type for the column. Then you can directly do comparisons with them.

Comment: is there any way from my current date format due to obviously my data type is a varchar to have it converted to str_to_date() format for use on a query?

Comment: or otherwise i need to give up the current format and force use native sql datetime